# FlexCel fails to open simple XLSX files

Tags: c#, excel, xlsx

A script I have works perfectly fine with XLS files, but throws errors when the same files are saved as XLSX (very simple test files). I am using FlexCel library, as per description: FlexCel Studio for .NET Framework 3.5 (with XLSX support).

The error occurs at the `.Open()` method:

> FlexCelXlsAdapterException : Error reading Excel records. File invalid
>   : FlexCel : at #c.#tl..ctor(Stream , Boolean ) at
>   FlexCel.XlsAdapter.XlsFile.#4rb(Stream , Boolean ) at
>   FlexCel.XlsAdapter.XlsFile.Open(Stream aStream, TFileFormats
>   fileFormat, Char delimiter, Int32 firstRow, Int32 firstCol,
>   ColumnImportType[] columnFormats, String[] dateFormats, Encoding
>   fileEncoding, Boolean detectEncodingFromByteOrderMarks) at
>   FlexCel.Core.ExcelFile.Open(Stream aStream, TFileFormats fileFormat,
>   Char delimiter, Int32 firstRow, Int32 firstCol, ColumnImportType[]
>   columnFormats) at FlexCel.Core.ExcelFile.Open(Stream aStream) at
>   UnhideOfficeContent.UnhideOfficeContent.UnhideExcelContent(String
>   filePath) at UnhideOfficeContent.UnhideOfficeContent.Execute() at
>   Sdl.Tms.MessageProcessing.WorkerRequestProcessor.ExecuteMessage()

I tried loading it from stream or reading the file, but it fails 100 % of the time with XLSX (but XLS is fine).

```
XlsFile xlsFile = new XlsFile(filePath);
//using (Stream xlsInputStream = File.OpenRead(filePath))
//{
//    xlsFile.Open(xlsInputStream,);
//}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please check the library version. It should be 5.6.7.0

[image]